# SVG Text Rotation Around the Center

Tags: jquery-svg

I have the text with textContent "Design" and text-anchor as start,  that was transformed with css to be rotated 45 degree. so it get rotated. problem is that i need to adjust the (x,y)position of the text after my rotation to display the text between the tick as shown in the Expected  figure. How can i achieve this.

Result:
http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img404/2711/result1h.png

Expected:
http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img266/5138/expected1.png

```
    <svg>
    <text x="100" y="100" width="64" height="16" fill="black" transform="rotate(45,100,100)" text-anchor="start">Design</text>
    </svg>
```

Thanks
Gowri

Comment: the links you posted are broken

Answer (score 15):

The text needs to be centered horizontally and vertically so rotation won't move it:

```
<text x="100" y="50" text-anchor="middle"
    dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(0, 100, 50)"></text>
```

`text-anchor` aligns the text horizontally
`dominant-baseline` aligns the text vertically

```css
svg {
    width: 200px; height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <text x="100" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(180, 100, 50)">
       Hello World
   </text>
    <text x="100" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" transform="rotate(0, 100, 50)">
       Hello World
   </text>
</svg>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/e4bAh/131/

Comment: Much simpler than every answer I've seen elsewhere, and it is the most accurate! Thanks for the jsfiddle

Answer (score 8):

use `transform="rotate(45, cx, cy)"`

Where `cx, cy` are the co-ordinates of the center of screen (or rotation).

[This is a good example](http://www.irony-maiden.com/svg/manyeggs.htm)

Comment: i have used transform="rotate(45,100,100)", i need to change my text position after rotation

Comment: The problem is to determine svg text's center.